# SPD 2013 Custom Edit Form default fields for content type

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list with content types enabled. Each content type has it own set of columns. The default display, edit, new forms haven't been tampered with. When I create a new edit form in Sharepoint Designer 2013, I've found that when I specify the content type in the advanced form options I get two outcomes. Sometimes I get just the fields for that content type. Other times I get all the fields in the list and have to manually remove the un-necessary ones.

I've tried this by creating a site level content type and a list level content type with the same results.

Does anybody know if this is normal behaviour or a bug or if somewhere along the line I've changed something in the list or the content type that causes this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your default content type. On creating new item, by default it will show columns that are in your default content type.